# How to retrieve all data points in a Cosm datastream?

Tags: api, rest, cosm

Given a datastream like https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/61916/datastreams/random5.json, I'd expect to be able to page through all the datapoints in a feed like so:

```
GET ?start=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z&interval=0&offset=0&limit=1000
GET ?start=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z&interval=0&offset=1000&limit=1000
GET ?start=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z&interval=0&offset=2000&limit=1000
...
```

But there does not appear to be an `offset` parameter, and Cosm requires a `start` and an `end` parameter that are no further than [6h apart](https://cosm.com/docs/v2/history.html). Do I really need to issue thousands of requests (i.e. one or more for each 6h interval, starting from the beginning of time), or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the way to paginate through every point is, as you say, to use interval=0, with the max per_page of 1000 and to split the request up into 6 hour chunks.

We're looking at increasing these limits now that our back end storage can handle it.

Sorry I can't give a better answer right now, but this should improve.

Comment: Thanks! The 1000 per page limit seems reasonable; what's troublesome is the 6h interval limit. Consider the case where you have sporadic data going back several years; you'd have to issue thousands of requests, even if there were no more than a few hundred datapoints altogether! So if you could just go ahead and drop the interval limit requirement, that'd be great :-)

Answer (score 0):

By setting the "interval" argument to the API, it seems to be possible to specify durations up to the maximum indicated by the [documentation](https://cosm.com/docs/v2/history.html) (up to an interval of 86400 seconds which supports a duration of up to a year).

This [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/99n5T/5/) shows a duration of approximately 3 weeks when used with an interval of 3600 seconds with a URL of the form:

```
http://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/79903/datastreams/Temperature.json?start=2012-10-15T08:00:00Z&end=2012-11-08T00:00:00Z&interval=3600&limit=1000
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't let me retrieve the original data points, just aggregated values.